# Default php include on all pages

Tags: php, html, include

On my site I have overall header and footer that are being created by functions `header()` and `footer()`, accessible in `overall.php` file. All sites are based on the same template so it looks like following:

```
<?
    include ("/overall.php");
    header();
    echo "<div>";
    // content of site
    echo "</div>";        
    footer();
?>
```

I am thinking about another solution - maybe make a function `createsite($content)`:

```
<?
    function createsite($content)
    {
        header();
        echo "<div>".$content."</div>";
        footer();
    }
?>
```

so that it would be simplier to create new page (there will be more than hundred of them). What are your ideas? I have been thinking about something like default include of `overall.php` on all sites. I hugely prefer clear PHP over frameworks like symfony or zend.

Comment: Clear PHP could help you to develop small things, but if you have to create something bigger you have to work with some framework (micro at least).

Comment: looks like you are trying to make an model view controller, try see all the parts [LINK HERE](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Aw28-krO7ZM) just what you need, and asks for

Comment: If your pages are static or blog like, I suggest just using one of the many available PHP frameworks such as Laravel or Cake.

Comment: I use `.htaccess` to redirect everything to a common php page and pass the desired page in as a GET argument. It can then `include($_GET['page'])` but make sure to validate!!!

Answer (score 3):

You will probably end up doing the same thing all of the frameworks are also doing, which is having a single point of entry for all your pages which will include all the neccesary functions (such as those in overall.php) and then redirecting the user to whichever actual page they want to see by including that as well.

Keep in mind that what you're currently building is (or rather, will be) a very basic framework in its own right.

Comment: okay thanks :) I am working on free hosting and I can never make any framework to work properly.